# java not found after install but java programs run

Tags: java, java-7

I updated my java to JDK 7 today and after installing I can run java programs and eclipse runs fine but http://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp says no working java detected. Also Minecraft won't log in and tekkit cant load anything from the internet.
I have tried adding java to the PATH variable to no avail. What am i missing?

Comment: What does `java -version` and `-javac -version` say?

Comment: Did you make sure the JRE was in with the JDK?

Comment: java - version says:
`java version "1.7.0_03"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_03-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 22.1-b02, mixed mode)`
and -javac -version doesnt recognise -javac as a command

Comment: That's because "-javac" isn't a command, "javac" is; use some common sense. In any case, "installed.jsp" is checking for the browser plugin; are you running Chrome?

Comment: Have you set the JAVA_HOME variable?

Comment: @DaveNewton i am running firefox at the moment because my chrome wont run. Sorry im rather new to java javac -version returns `javac 1.7.0_03`

Comment: @Skierz 'installed' is still looking for the browser plugin, I'd start by searching the web for how to install the plugin. No clue about minecraft or tekkit, don't even know what they are.

Comment: @Tobias there is no JAVA_HOME variable in environment variables and java 6 worked fine without it but now i see a QTJava which has `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip` as its value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, java is not detected on my machine by this jsp as well.

I believe this happens because JSP cannot *really* detect java *installed* on your machine. It can only detect version of Java plugin installed on your current browser. So, you have to install java plugin (if you need it).

Answer (score 0):

Installing the JDK doesn't necessarily install the Java plugin in your browser(s).
Assuming you are on Windows, follow these steps:

- Open Control Panel
- Open Java
- Click the 'Java' tab
- Click 'View'
- Click the checkbox in the 'Enabled' column for the JRE you want to enable. If you can't see one then click 'Add' to add it (by specifying the path to the java exe)
- Restart your browser

Comment: There is only 1 JRE in there and it is enabled

Comment: Is it JDK 7 i.e. the one you installed? If not, check the value in the path column for that JRE is valid - maybe when you installed JDK 7 you uninstalled the JRE that was there before? In which case, remove that (click 'Remove') and add the JRE for JDK 7 (click 'Find' and to save time in the wizard start in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0 or whereever)

Comment: the JRE variables are correct and the correct version is running on my computer

Comment: Go to Control Panel->Java->Advanced (tab) and and select Java console->Show console. Revisit www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp and see if you see the Java console.

Comment: i dont see any consoles when i revisit with it enabled (in firefox and IE)

Comment: Just to be clear - on the 'Java' tab (in Control Panel->Java) is the JRE that showing Java 7? i.e. is its path (in the path column) something like C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\bin\java.exe?

Comment: it is showing C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe

Comment: So it looks like you had JRE7 installed previously. Presumably C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe still exists on your hard disk? Anyway, you could try removing this (from the Java control panel) and then adding the JRE that comes with the JDK you just installed, i.e. something like C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe (although you should add it using the 'Find' button). Then restart your browsers and try again.